# postgresql server fail to start ubuntu?

Tags: server, boot, postgresql

I have an ubuntu system and installed postgresql server on ubuntu. Till yesterday evening its working fine and I did shutdown it properly. Today morning when I started it then it boot and gave the below error

```
The postgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:              [fail]
Speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
checking for running unattended-upgrades.                                        [ok]
*starting bluetooth
*pulse audio configured for per-user sessions
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned                                          [ok]
*checking battery status...
```

on this step system stay and nothing happens

please help me to short out this issue
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be due to space problem. 
first boot the system & then press f8 key. 
In this some option to be show.

> - check disk
> - try to free space
> - and more

you can try both check-disk & free space option & after completion the system boot normally.

Comment: OK if you have more problem then ask me.